# React Native Flex Child Growth Seemingly Affected by Padding

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am experiencing some difficulty when using flex for layout in React Native. I have reduced the behaviour I am experiencing down the the following problem.

I have one container which fills the available space since it has flex set to 1. I then have a child within that container which should fill the container, so I have set it's flex to 1. I also want the container to have padding at the top. I would therefore expect the child to fill all of the parent apart from the top 20%. However, what I am seeing is that there is equal padding at the top and bottom of the container around the child (as if I had set paddingVertical instead of paddingTop).

Is anyone able to explain why this behaves as it does? I am also intrigued by the behavior I saw when creating a snack to illustrate this problem. On the iOS and Android simulators I am experiencing the behaviour which seems erroneous to me whereas the Web view seems to work as I would expect with only a gap at the top.

Thanks!

[Snack example code](https://snack.expo.io/@robertnash/rude-pretzels)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Text>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    paddingTop: '20%'
  },
  child: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'red'
  },
});
```

Android - 'broken' behaviour
[image]
Web - 'expected' behaviour
[image]

Comment: This is indeed very weird. You might want to open an issue on the react-native repository on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this @romin21